# Difference in amount of samples, does that affect my chi squared test?

Tags: python, chi-squared-test

So I have the following pandas crosstab table

[image]

```
a = np.array([[1844,  119],
       [4139,  367]])
```

As you can see the amount of user who are in the "não repescado" category. Surpass, considerably the amount of users in the "repescado" category. In this case, should I aim to make the amount of samples of each side equivalent since the test is frequency based I ought to believe to follow this line of thought? Or I can make the test without a care? If so how come I can do it without a care? Asking this question because when I learned all sample seen to have the same amount on each row and column sum

Comment: As a partial answer, the chi-square test of association will work fine when the column sums or row sums are far from equal.  In any case, you ***don't*** want to try to adjust the counts in the table to make e.g. the column sums equal. ...  For your table, what may be more informative than the chi-square test is to look at the proportions within each column or row (whichever makes sense).  For example, the proportions in column 1 are 0.31 and 0.69. And the proportions in  column 2 are 0.24 and 0.76.  Whether the difference in these proportions across columns is meaningful, is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will affect the Chi-square test of independence, and in short, you should probably not do what you suggest.

You can test it for yourself, by making the number of observations *repescado*  similar to *não repescado*, while retaining the original distribution of *repescado* (something like 24.5% for *finalizou*, and 75.5% for *não finalizou*).

Your original table returns a Chi-square value of $\approx 8.238$. But here's what happens if you increase *repescado*  up to 5983 observations ($1465+4518$ if we retain the "24.5% & 75.5%" distribution):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(
       data=np.array([[1844,  1465],
                      [4139,  4518]]), 
       columns=["não repescado", "repescado"],
       index=["finalizou", "não finalizou"])

print("chi2 value =", chi2_contingency(a)[0])
```

> chi2 value = 59.685441879817624

This will affect the p-value and the conclusion you can draw from your dataset. It is almost certainly not a good idea, depending on what you want to know.

If you increase your sample size by oversampling people in the *repescado* category, you won't be able to make valid inferences on the population anymore -assuming your original sample is a random sample from your population of interest. (In other words, your sample will be biased and won't be "representative" of your population anymore - even if strictly speaking, "representative" is [an abuse of language](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/RandomSampleImportance.html)).

So if you're interested in drawing conclusions about the population from which your sample comes from, don't oversample the *repescado* category, and use the chi-square test (or even the [Fisher exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) for $2 \times 2$ tables like this one).

If you're interested in comparing the *repescado* and *não repescado* categories, oversampling *might* be a reasonable idea, but then you probably shouldn't use a chi-square test for that (for example, look into analyzing [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) instead). In this case, it's probably worth asking another question, where you'd explain more in detail what you want to learn from your dataset exactly.

Comment: In this case odds ratios is actually very interesting. I guess it will give me the odd of a certain group that is exposed to that new flux, and a group that is not. And tell me which group will be more susceptible to the wanted closure

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 You might want asking another question about it, to know which analysis method is best given the way you collect your data (as there are others measures than odds ratios, like the risk ratio, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4640017/ for example).